# Abonos vs. billetes

Tags: significado

¿Existe alguna diferencia de significado entre "abonos" y  "billetes? Creo que las dos palabras se traducen en inglés como "tickets", ¿no es así? Si la respuesta es un "sí", ¿entonces por qué en este [enlace](https://www.crtm.es/billetes-y-tarifas/billetes-y-abonos.aspx) no se usa solo una de las dos palabras?  ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Generalmente, el abono incluye varios viajes. Ejemplos: abono de 10 viajes, abono de viajes ilimitados. Por otro lado, el billete suele ser de ida o ida y vuelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Billete es un solo viaje de ida o ida y vuelta. Abono es un pack de viajes ya sea por cantidad (10 viajes), tiempo (diario, semanal, mensual, anual, etc.) o combinación de transportes (bus-tren).

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por las detallafas explicaciones de Ustedes! Y perdonen por no haber podido responder antes ...

Answer (score 0):

You suggest in your question that both *billete* and *abono* are translated into English as ticket. This is only partly true.

A single or return is indeed a ticket.

A season (ticket) is one valid for journeys on the same route for a specified period: weekly season, monthly season, etc. Note that most English speaker just call it a season.

We do not usually have something like the *abono* which covers 10 trips but if we did we use the French word, carnet.

To further confuse the issue combined travel on various systems like bus/train/tram is usually done with a travelcard.

So my feeling is that you did not realise that we have such a complicated system compared to the Spanish one.

Answer (score 0):

*Abono* está relacionado con *abonar(se)*. Implica que lo que se paga no es un billete único "a la carta", sino algo que permite viajar repetidamente.

> RAE: [**Abonar²**](https://dle.rae.es/abonar?m=form) Hacer que alguien adquiera, mediante pago, el derecho a disponer de un servicio, recibir publicaciones, o acudir a un local de espectáculos, durante un tiempo determinado o un cierto número de veces. U. m. c. prnl. Me he abonado A la ópera.

El francés tiene *abonnement* con este sentido.